# Missing Zero value in addtional y axis range silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, radchart

We are using RadChart in silverlight application.The chart is having multi y-axis(Two) one is showing the ranging from zero to 100 but another y axis is not showing the ranging from 0 to 100.It is showing the range from the point binding -1 to +1 of that value(i.e the value is 80 means the scale will be 79,80,81).

can any provide me any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```
        AxisY axisY = new AxisY();
        axisY.AxisName = "AxisY1";
        axisY.Title = "";
        axisY.IsZeroBased = true;
```